# Updating Stored Procedure on Three Different Servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to update the SQL SERVER stored procedure on three different servers. I do not like to perform this manually. What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SQLCMD utility to connect to the three different servers / databases and run the stored procedure script.  The control script may look something like this:

```
:connect server1
use DatabaseName
GO
:r StoredProcedure.sql
GO

:connect server2
use DatabaseName
GO
:r StoredProcedure.sql
GO

:connect server3
use DatabaseName
GO
:r StoredProcedure.sql
GO
```

SQL Compare is a great tool, especially for large or complex updates.  However, you do have to pay for it.  Using a utility like SQLCMD is not quite so elegant, but it is quick and free.

Comment: Thanks! I think I might go the route of executing everything in Query Analyzer.

Comment: How do I say use servername.databasename? The server is already added in the sys.servers. use [ServerName].[DatabaseName] does not work!

Comment: You need to specify everything as I have above.  The :connect statement is used to change the connection to a different server.  The USE statement just switches to a different database.  If you are going to execute this through a GUI of sorts, you need to use SQL Management Studio (not query analyzer) and you need to make sure the menu option found under Query -> SQLCMD mode is checked ON.  Otherwise, the statements prefixed with a colon (:) will not be recognized.  They are SQLCMD specific commands, not part of T-SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool like Red-Gate SQL Compare to create a script and then use their Multi-Script tool to execute it on multiple servers at one time.

www.red-gate.com

Answer (score 1):

You could use a SQL Server synchronization tool, such as Red Gate **[SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index-2.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=sqlcompare&gclid=CI3Pt8ynhqACFQVinAodKDZLtA)**.   Or you could write a small script / application to connect to each server and execute the update statement, using **[OSQL](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index-2.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=sqlcompare&gclid=CI3Pt8ynhqACFQVinAodKDZLtA)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up some replication between the servers...have 1 main server that you make the update on, and then send that update out to each other server by use of a publication to the other servers.  That'd be an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Migrator.NET](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/), this combined with a builder like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) that runs on a check-in should do the trick.  Plus you get versioning and rollbacks along with it.

Answer (score 0):

With "Central Management Servers" feature of SQL Server 2008, what you can do is to add those three servers into one group and then run a single alter procedure script against these three servers.